# Where can I find a form once placed in a site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, microsoft-forms

I created a form in SharePoint online (via - https://www.office.com/launch/forms?auth=2) and the moved it into a group. All good. I can see the form within "Forms" as part of that group.

I can also create a web part in the group's site that has a form in it.

What I want to do is instead of leaping from one app to another, use the team's site to centralize documents, lists, FORMS etc.

Is there any way I can make the form magically appear on the group site?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Forms** is another service which is not a part of SharePoint Online. You can use the Forms web part to help end users to response or display the statistics of the survey. However you will not be able to "add" it to your team site.

Comment: Ok, I got it... So a different service. IMO, it makes a lot of sense to host forms and their results within a certain team. Forms are a great structured interaction tool and can become part of many processes within a company. 
What threw me completely off is that I can add the form to a group (Move it) - but I can't see it anywhere but in the forms service site. Which I find completely backwards... and awkward.

Is that the features' intent?

Comment: @RazvanCostea-Barlutiu, I am not an expert on forms, only depending on my experience, move the forms to an group simply makes it to a group form. Still this is part of the Forms functionality. It means all the group member will be able to view and edit it. It is part of the integration of the M365. You can directly handle M365 group in other apps like forms.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft forms will not be stored/shown on SharePoint directly.

If you want users to respond to Microsoft forms from SharePoint site then you need to create a SharePoint modern page and add Microsoft form on page using **Microsoft Forms web part**.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Use the Microsoft Forms web part](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-microsoft-forms-web-part-d4b4d3ce-7860-41e4-8a98-76380efe7256)